# How to apply regular expression with CDATA in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm using regular expressions with XSLT 2.0 to validate XMLs and and I don't know how to validate fields with elements CDATA like this XML:

```
    <cac:Item>
        <cbc:Description><![CDATA[   ]]></cbc:Description>
        <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>8510</cbc:ID>
        </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
    </cac:Item>
```

Mi XSLT is:

```
    <xsl:if test='not(matches(cac:Item/cbc:Description,"^.{1,250}$"))'>
```

This expression returns false because the element cbc:Description have 15 characters, but I just want to validate element inside CDATA. I tried with this template:

```
    <xsl:template name="valueCDATA" match="text()">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$node"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="getCDATA">
        <xsl:call-template name="valueCDATA">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="cac:Item/cbc:Description"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
```

But it doesn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Do you have an `xsl:strip-space` element (like `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`) in your stylesheet? If so, `cbc:Description` will have zero characters. Also, the `<![CDATA[]]>` piece do not count as characters so really there are only 3.

Comment: Yes, with xsl:strip-space element I would have <![CDATA[]]> and that is I want it, I have xsl:strip-space to have zero characteres.

Comment: If that's the case your `test` will return true (because a zero length string does not match your regex).

Comment: It returns false because the element  <![CDATA[]]> is taken like a string with 12 characters. I want to validate just data inside <![CDATA[]]> but I dont know how do it.

Comment: When the tree is built, `<![CDATA[]]>` doesn't exist as text. Try `<xsl:value-of select="string-length(cac:Item/cbc:Description)"/>` and it should output `0`.

Comment: I'm sorry, you have all the reason. I had not been using correctly the expression, all my apologies for my wrong. Thank you so much @Daniel Haley